# RSA encryption sometimes works other time won't

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, discrete-mathematics

Guys I really need your help, is this code correct? sometimes if I run it and change the word IMAHACKER to THANKYOU or anything it would work but when I run it again it wouldn't show the message. I think the problem is with the generated numbers? but how do I fix it. I'd really appreciate it if you help because I can't seem to figure out the mistake!

```
import java.util.*;
public class R{
   private Random rnd= new Random();


   //Finds the greatest common divisor of two integers, a and b
   //Input: a and b integers
   //Output: gcd of a and b, using Euclidean method   
   public long gcd(long a, long b) {
      if (b==0) 
         return a;
      return gcd(b,a%b);
   } 

   //Finds the multiplicative inverse of a modulo m
   //Input: a an integer, and modulus m
   //Output: i: inverse of a modulo m, such that (a*i mod m)=1
   public long find_inverse(long a, long m)
   {    
      for (long i=1; i<m; i++)  
      {
         long test=i*a;
         if ((test%m)==1)
            return i;
      }
      return 0;
   }

   //Generates a random prime number
   //Input: None
   //Output: A random prime number between 2 and 10000 
   public int random_prime()
   {
      boolean found=false;
      int p=0;
      while (!found)
      {
         p=rnd.nextInt(10000);
         found= isPrime(p);
      }
      return p;      
   }


   //Check if a number is prime or not
   //Input: integer p
   //Output: True if p is a prime number 
   //and False if it is composite
   public boolean isPrime(int p)
   {
      if (p>1){
         for (int i=2; i<= Math.sqrt(p); i++)
         {
            if (p%i==0)
               return false;
         }
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
   static long t=0;
   //Generate Keys method
   //Input: None
   //Output: n_e_d an array of longs containing:
   //n_e_d[0]: the modulus n(which is p*q)
   //n_e_d[1]: the exponent d(public key)
   //n_e_d[2]: d is inverse of e modulo (p-1)*(q-1) (private key)
   public long[] generate_keys()
   {
      long[] n_e_d= new long[3]; 
      int p = random_prime();
      int q = random_prime();

      long n = p*q;

      long euler = (p-1)*(q-1);
      t = euler;
      int e = random_prime();
      long GCD = gcd (e, euler);

      while ( e > euler && e < 1 && GCD != 1 )
         e = random_prime();

      long d = find_inverse(e, euler);

      n_e_d[0] = n;
      n_e_d[1] = e;
      n_e_d[2] = d;
      return n_e_d;
   }



   //Find (b^n mod m) when we are dealing with big numbers
   //Same as algorithm 5 in 4.2 in the book
   //Input: b: the base, n: the exponent, and m: the modulus
   //All inputs are in decimal representation
   //Output: Value of (b^n mod m)
   public long modular_exponentiation(long b, long n, long m)
   {
      long x=1;
      long pow=b%m;

      //COMPLETE HERE (approx 5 lines)
      //Convert n to binary (use method Long.toBinaryString(..))
      //Iterate over the length of n
      //Change pow and x as necessary
      String nBi = Long.toBinaryString(n);
      int a = 0;
      for(int i=0;i<nBi.length();i++){
      a = Character.getNumericValue(nBi.charAt(nBi.length()-(i+1)));
      if(a==1)
      x=(x*pow)%m;
      pow=((long)Math.pow(pow,2))%m;}

      return x;
   }

   //Convert from String_to_int
   //Make sure you use two digits for each letter (e.g. 01 instead of 1)
   //e.g. Input:KBL, Output: 100111  
   public long string_to_int(String text)
   {
      //COMPLETE HERE (approx 6 lines)
      long num = 0;
      String concat ="";

      for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
      {
         char c = text.charAt(i);
         String rep = String.valueOf( c - 65 );

         if ( rep.length() < 2 )
            rep = "0" + rep;

         concat = concat + rep ;

         num = Long.parseLong(concat);
      }
      return num;  
   }


   //Convert from int_to_String
   //e.g. Input: 100111, Output:KBL 
   public String int_to_String(long inttext)
   {
   String text="";
   long num=0;
   while(inttext>1){
   num= inttext%100;
   text = String.valueOf((char)(num+65))+text;
   inttext = inttext/100;
   }
   return text;
   /*
      String text="";
      String i = inttext + "";
      for(int j=0;j<i.length();j+=2)
      text +=Integer.parseInt(i.charAt(j)+""+i.charAt(j+1))>-1 && Integer.parseInt(i.charAt(j)+""+i.charAt(j+1))<26? String.valueOf((char)((Integer.parseInt(i.charAt(j)+""+i.charAt(j+1)))+65)) : null;      
      return text;*/

   }


   public int intoBlocks(String s){
   int len=0;
   int c=0;

   if(s.length()%2==0)
   len = s.length()/2;
   else
   len=(s.length()/2)-1;

  // System.out.println(len);


   return len;
   }
   public String[] ArrayinBlocks(String s, int x){
   String arr[] = new String[s.length()/x];
   int j=0;

   for(int i=0;i<s.length();i+=x){
   arr[j]=s.substring(i,Math.min(s.length(),(i+x)));
   j++;}

   return arr;
   }

   //Encryption method
   //Input: plaintext, e and n, where:
   //Plaintext is a String of uppercase letters only
   //e is the public key
   //n is the modulus
   //Output: Ciphertext, which is an array of longs, each element
   // represents the ciphertext of the ith block
   public long[] encrypt(String plaintext, long e, long n)
   {long[] ciphertext;

      int block=intoBlocks(plaintext); 
         //System.out.println(block);
      int t = block;  
      if(block%2==0){
      t = block/2;
      ciphertext=new long[block/2];}
      else
      ciphertext=new long[block];
      long C;
      //COMPLETE HERE (approx 10 lines)
      //Split text into blocks of appropriate size, get their integer representation,
      String arr[] = ArrayinBlocks(plaintext,intoBlocks(plaintext));

     // System.out.println(arr[0] + " " + arr[1]);

      for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
      ciphertext[i] = string_to_int(arr[i]);
      System.out.println(ciphertext[0] + " " + ciphertext[1]);

      for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
      ciphertext[i] = modular_exponentiation(ciphertext[i], e, n);

      return ciphertext;
   }


   //Decryption method
   //Input: ciphertext, d and n, where:
   //Ciphertext is an array of longs, each element represents the ciphertext of the ith block
   //d is the private key
   //n is the modulus
   //Output: Plaintext as a String
   public String decrypt(long[] ciphertext, long d, long n)
   {
   String plaintext="";
   for(int i=0;i<ciphertext.length;i++)
   plaintext+=int_to_String(modular_exponentiation(ciphertext[i],d,n));


   return plaintext;


   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      R cipher= new R(); //Create an instance of your cryptographic system

      //Before starting, you must generate your keys
      long[] n_e_d= cipher.generate_keys();
      System.out.println("Modulus n is: "+n_e_d[0]);
      System.out.println("Public key e is: "+n_e_d[1]);
      System.out.println("Private key d is: "+ n_e_d[2]);

      //Encrypt the plaintext using exponent e and modulus n
      long[] ciphertext=cipher.encrypt("IMAHACKER", n_e_d[1],n_e_d[0]);
      //Print each of the ciphertext blocks
      for (long block: ciphertext)
         System.out.print (block+ " ");
      System.out.println();

      //Decrypt the ciphertext and print out the plaintext
      String plaintext=cipher.decrypt(ciphertext, n_e_d[2], n_e_d[0]);
      System.out.println("Decrypting ciphertext we get: "+plaintext);

   }

}
```

Comment: Didn't I just see this exact question a day or two ago?

Comment: first bug I've found: you need to recompute the GCD(e, euler) every time though the `e` loop. Also, the `&&` conditions of that loop should be `||`.

Comment: I guess `intoBlocks()` is an attempt to compute the number of blocks? I can't figure out what you're trying to do there.

Comment: Lots more bugs and confusing code. Bottom line: your blocking scheme doesn't seem to be a function of the modulus, and the modulus can be anything from 6 to 20000, so the scheme is doomed to fail for small moduli.

Comment: Indeed. **Divide and Conquer!** Try and split your problem up in parts, like you try to do with your plain text blocks. Create a function to split and combine given some sized integer (like the modulus) and test that separately. Try and *localize* your issue; please do not expect us to do that for you. Debugging large swaths of code is not what SO is about. And if you do post code, please minimalize it; at least remove the uncommented out code parts.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: how do you get 20000? I make it 4 to 9973^2=99460729 because generate_keys does not enforce distinct primes as is required for RSA, although given Java's `Random` is decent the probability of duplication should be about 1/pi(10000). Also for at least some numbers toward the top of that range, `Math.pow(x,2)` gives inexact result.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: you're right, mine was a quick and careless read of very careless code. I must've multiplied by 2 instead of squaring.